# Member variable holds junk values after assignment

Tags: c++, class, debugging, compiler-optimization

I have encountered a weird scenario which I can't figure out why it happens.

I have an object with a simple `int` member.

className.h file:

```
private:
  int       m_variable;

public:
                   ...
(constructor and the rest of the functions)  
                   ...
```

className.cpp file:

```
void className::function()
{
    ...
    m_variable = pointerToOtherClass->getMaxDistOfAllMatrices(); //first call
    int x = pointerToOtherClass->getMaxDistOfAllMatrices();     //second call
    m_variable = x;

    cout << m_variable  << "," << x;
}
```

The functions of the first call and the second call, are the same, i.e. will return the same value.

When I put a breakpoint on the first call and step over the calls, I see that `m_variable`  hols junk and `x` hold 4 (the expected result). The line `m_variable = x;` changes nothing (`x=4`, `m_variable` still holds junk)  and after the `cout`  it prints `4,4` which is as expected.

The line of `first call`, is the first time the code meets `m_variable`.

I don't understand why does it happen, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you enabled debugging (and disabled optimization) while compiling the code?

Comment: Release mode instead of debug mode maybe ?

Comment: Do you compile with optimization flags? -Ox? If so, try without them.

Comment: You should try to turn off the optimizations while compiling and check. Use  -O0  for no optimization.

Comment: `m_variable` holds junk, `m_variable=x;` does nothing, `cout` prints correct values... this is somehow not consistent. Are you sure, you are debugging the right way?

Comment: the optimization is disabled..

Comment: I enabled debugging and it worked. Mohit Jain, thank you for your answer, but you didn't have to give me (-1) for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing optimization artifacts. 
Storing the **first** result of the function `getMaxDistOfAllMatrices()` to the variable `m_variable` is omitted because two lines later that first call the result of a second call to the function is stored again to that variable (via `x`).

`x` holds the expected value since it is used later on in `cout`.
Note that the function called is not omitted (called twice) since it may have side effects, but it is valid to ignore the first result.

```
m_variable = ponterToOtherClass->getMaxDistOfAllMatrices(); //first call
```

You may see garbage in `m_variable` after stepping over above line.

```
int x = ponterToOtherClass->getMaxDistOfAllMatrices();     //second call
m_variable = x;
```

You see expected values in both variables after stepping over above two lines.